# Play mp3/wav file from memorystream to webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, mp3, wav

Recently I was approached to develop an application (asp.net/c#) to allow users to listen some audio files stored in some shared folders.

The users didn't have access to the shared folders, and the files should be streamed. Also, the page should provide the play/stop/pause/forward/back functions, as well as time elapsed/total time information.

So I setup a webservice that access the required file, and return a Byte[] containing the mp3/wav audio (actually I have to convert them to the desired mp3/wav format prior to returning the Byte[]).

The problem is that I have no idea on how to present it in the webpage.

What i need is a webpage with some control that provides the necessary functionalities and information, loaded from a Byte[].

I've researched the web and tried a lot of snippets and controls with no luck at all.

Any ideas or directions on how to implement it?

Thanks in Advance,
António

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [HTML5's audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp), if you expect your users to be using fairly recent browser versions.  You'd set the `src` to a URL that would be set up to write your `byte[]` to the response stream (e.g. maybe store the `byte[]` in `Session`, make an .ashx handler page to return that, and set `src="myHandler.ashx"`).

Comment: Thanks you.

I've make some preliminary testing and everything indicates that it could work. I didn't event think of using a handler!

Eventually the users would have to upgrade the browser versions but hey, they will have what they want to :)

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to use silverlight or flash player, even a java applet.